# Why the jquery not working in bootstrap4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I started using bootstrap. but, the jquery not working. what the problem in here?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p id="test"></p>

<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $("#test").html("Hello World."); }); </script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Not working how?

Comment: @King11 i don't know, i using all dependecies from cdn that bootstrap provide. the jquery not working. i tried also from jquery cdn website. its not working also. if i include bootstrap from cdn.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "the jquery not working"? What behaviour did you expect, what do you observe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use these links and place at the top of your file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2mw57sbu/

Comment: From your browser is working?

Comment: i tested in latest chrome and firefox. the jquery not working.

Comment: Yeah it works on my broswer.  The jsfiddle isn't working? Remove your old `script` tags and replace with the ones in my answer.

Comment: in jsfiddle is working. i try in browser not working. can u test in your browser please from source.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of chrome 78.0 and it works fine

Comment: I means u create index.html with that source and let me know.

Comment: Yes, just did. It works fine when I open index.html in Chrome and IE. Did you copy everything I have in the jsfiddle and paste into index.html for yourself? Also do you have any errors in your console/DOM?

Comment: i know now. the jquery file have to put in top  before other code.

Comment: Yes, I was about to ask you do you have the tags at the top of your page, and usually they should be in an `head` tag but since you did not have one, I did not add one. But the `script` tags in my answer should work as well.

Comment: @stephenchou will you mark this as the accepted answer so that this question is resolved if you have everything working